# Scala open ports

Tags: scala, ubuntu

So I have been running a few scala programs on Ubunutu and I have noticed that whenever I run a program for some reason Java starts listening on some random port and won't stop listening. 
I am running scala version 2.9.2 on ubuntu 14.10. 
Is this meant to happen and does it happen for anyone else?

To check open ports I am using 
sudo netstat -anltp
lsof -i

Thanks

Comment: Scala/java is not supposed to simply start listening on a random port, but there are many reasons this could happen : enabling jmx, starting a program which does network io etc. Maybe you can share more details (which programs do you run, what are your javaopts, etc) and run a couple diagnostic commands and paste the result : jcmd <PID> VM.system_properties, jcmd <PID> VM.command_line, jcmd <PID> VM.flags would be a good start.

Comment: So for an example program even if I just type "scala" on the terminal and then quit. or if I compile a program that just prints a line I will get the port listening. After a bit more investigation it also appears to only occur when I compile with fsc as opposed to scalac. Could you recommend any good diagnostic commands? I am not a very technical person. Thanks

Comment: I gave 3 diagnostic commands in my previous comment. PID is the process id which you want to inspect. you can get a list of the processes by running jcmd without arguments. FSC will open and bind a port since it is a compilation server, however once the programs are compiled and FSC is shut down there should be no ports open. in what range are the bound ports you observe ?

Comment: So if i shutdown the fsc server manually using fsc -shutdown the process stops listening. The ports are quite high (10,000s).